# fix a bad div with greasemonekey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I'm trying to fix a div using greasemonkey. This specific one is designed to be an anti-adblock measure. It hides the spoiler by pretending to be a google ad.

```html
<div class="bbCodeBlock-content adsbygoogle">
```

How can I remove the adsbygoogle from this div with greasemonkey?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add this script

```
    document.getElementsByClassName('adsbygoogle')[0].classList.remove('adsbygoogle');
```

Or to do it asynchronously

```
    function remove() {
        if (document.getElementsByClassName('adsbygoogle').length) {
            document.getElementsByClassName('adsbygoogle'[0].classList.remove('adsbygoogle');
        } else {
            setTimeout(remove, 100);
        }
    }

    remove();
```